# RestAssured : How to make the POST rest assure call abstract for different type of Request objects

Tags: java, rest-assured

Currently this is what my post call is :

```
private static Response postRequest(String endpoint, ABC request, int expectedStatusCode) {
    return extractResponse(buildRequest().body(request).post(endpoint), expectedStatusCode);
}
```

Now I am adding another post endpoint call but the request object type is different. Something like this :

```
 private static Response postRequest(String endpoint, XYZ request, int expectedStatusCode) {
    return extractResponse(buildRequest().body(request).post(endpoint), expectedStatusCode);
}
```

How can I overload just the type of request without having redundant code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use java generics:

```
private static <T> Response postRequest(String endpoint, T request, int expectedStatusCode) {...}
```